# Does AngularUI Bootstrap come with the css included?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower

Sorry if this is obvious but [their site](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) lists Bootstrap css as a dependency, I have installed the angular bootstrap package with bower and used it to build a page, but it does not look as intended, it looks similar to what happens when regular bootstrap fails to load.

I can see in the package bower installed some `.less` files but they seem too few to cover most of the widgets angular ui bootstrap boasts, so my question is does the bootstrap css come with the angular ui bootstrap module (from bower) or must it be installed separately ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the doc is clear enough :

> Dependencies
>
> This repository contains a set of native AngularJS directives based on
>   Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or
>   Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only required dependencies
>   are:
>
> ```
> AngularJS (minimal version 1.0.8)
> Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 3.0.3). This version of the library (0.10.0) works only with Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0
> ```
>
> is the last version of this library that supports Bootstrap CSS in
>   version 2.3.x.

cf : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Angular-ui-bootstrap contains mainly JS directives and templates to angularjsify it.

Note that their is also a `angular-bootstrap` bower package that contains html2js-ready templates.